# Particular solution of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve system of differential equations
$$\begin{cases}
x'(t)=2y(t)-x(t)+1 \\
y'(t)=3y(t)-2x(t).
\end{cases}
$$

My solution:

First, I find the characteristic values
$$\begin{vmatrix}
3-\lambda & -2 \\ 2 & -1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=-(3-\lambda)(1+\lambda)+4=0\Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}=1$$
next, eigenvectors
$$\begin{cases}
2x_1-2x_2=0 \\
2x_1-2x_2=0
\end{cases}\Rightarrow x_1=1, \ x_2=1 \Rightarrow P_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{cases}
2x_1-2x_2=1 \\
2x_1-2x_2=1
\end{cases}\Rightarrow x_1=2, \ x_2=3\Rightarrow P_2=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$
This means that
$$y_h=C_1e^tP_1+C_2e^t(tP_1+P_2)$$
Since our system is nonhomogeneous, we also need to find $y_*$, the particular solution. I would appreciate some information about the method.

Comment: You have a first order system with a polynomial of degree $0$ as the forcing. This motivates assuming that the particular solution is a polynomial of degree $1$. Now identify the (four) coefficients.